# setting the background colour from program rather than from xml for fragments

Tags: android

I need some help in setting the background colour using code for my current fragment. The fragment is created on selecting a particular tab.

Below is my main activity code

```
public class TabActionBarActivity extends Activity { 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        

    // Set the text and background colour
    setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();



    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);



    String label6 = getResources().getString(R.string.label6);
    tab = actionBar.newTab();
    tab.setText(label6);
    TabListener<Tab6Fragment> tl6 = new TabListener<Tab6Fragment>(this,
            label6, Tab6Fragment.class);
    tab.setTabListener(tl6);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    String label7 = getResources().getString(R.string.label7);
    tab = actionBar.newTab();
    tab.setText(label7);
    TabListener<Tab7Fragment> tl7 = new TabListener<Tab7Fragment>(this,
            label7, Tab7Fragment.class);
    tab.setTabListener(tl7);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);        


}
```

Now the code for the Tab7Fragment class looks like this

```
    public class Tab7Fragment extends Fragment {

   TextView tv1;

   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {        

        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this.getActivity());

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this.getActivity());
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        sv.addView(ll);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this.getActivity());
        tv.setText("Dynamic layouts ftw!");
        ll.addView(tv);

        EditText et = new EditText(this.getActivity());
        et.setText("weeeeeeeeeee~!");
        ll.addView(et);

        Button b = new Button(this.getActivity());
        b.setText("I don't do anything, but I was added dynamically. :)");
        ll.addView(b);

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this.getActivity());
            cb.setText("I'm dynamic!");
            ll.addView(cb);
        }
        return this.getView();
    }
```

}

Now how can i set the view for this fragment?

```
this.getActivity().setContentView(sv);
```

I know the above method is incorrect. But i need to set the content view with the scrollview layout. and another question is how do i set the background colour for this view?(using setBackgroundColor()?

Comment: try sv.setBackgroundColor(getRessources().getColors(R.color.yourcolor));

Comment: thanks for your reply for setting the colour. What about setting the layout for this fragment? I cant use setContentView(sv) from a fragemnt

Comment: I put my proposition in the response below, please accept it if it was useful to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your onCreateView():

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);
```

Then dont forget to return the view that you just inflated to the android runtime.

Remove `return this.getView();` and add `return view;`

Comment: thanks for your reply. I do not have a xml layout for this fragment. I am dynamically generating this layout, so cannot use the inflate method.

Answer (score 0):

To set background color :

```
sv.setBackgroundColor(getRessources().getColors(R.color.yourcolor));
```

To inflate layout into a fragment, you need to return a View from onCreateView :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle  savedInstanceState)     {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your layout, container, false);
 }
```

Comment: I want to create the layout for this fragment from code rather than an xml. So I cannot use the inflate method.

Comment: I understand what you want but i'm not an expert in fragment, sorry... You can find useful way here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html